# How can I fix "lscfg is not supported on the Unknown" for Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pci

I wanted to get information about the physical location of my PCI cards and found that lscfg for AIX looked like what I needed. [lsvpd-1.7.4](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linux-diag/files/lsvpd-new/) that includes lscfg does exist for Linux. As I am developing on Ubuntu 10.4 I had to get these two other libs:

- libvpd-2.2.1 (trial and error for this one really)
- librtas-1.3.12 (just the most recent version)

After successfully compiling and installing the lsvpd tools I ran lscfg and the other tools. Sadly, I get the response "lscfg is not supported on the Unknown" for this and a similar ones for all the other tools. Do these tools not work on Ubuntu Linux or Linux in general? Can I fix my problem somehow? The tools seem to be in active development for rpm-based systems.

---

**Note:**
In particular, I need a line like this for my network adapters (and possibly other cards):

"eth0             U787A.001.DNZ00Z5-P1-T5" (Source: Zombiep Process WordPress blog)

and wouldn't mind any other Ubuntu Linux program that can do that. I started a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908782/in-linux-is-there-a-way-to-find-out-which-pci-card-is-plugged-into-which-pci-sl) about tools for the job on Stackoverflow already but didn't get the answer that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, lscfg and the lsvpd tools in general are developed for the PowerPC platform and there is no support for x86 based systems. So, there goes my hope for that one.

The best way to get information about the tool is the mailing list you find [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linux-diag/). Many thanks to those guys for their quick response.